# How to do multiple dispatch() inside ng2-redux?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux

Currently i use `ng2-redux` inside Angular app, so if we want to dispatch **single action** we would do something like:

```
onClick() {
  this.ng2redux.dispatch({type: ACTION01 });
}
```

But, what if we want to dispatch **multiple actions**?, currently the way i implemented is something like

```
onClick() {
      this.ng2redux.dispatch({type: ACTION01 });
      this.ng2redux.dispatch({type: ACTION02 });
      this.ng2redux.dispatch({type: ACTION03 });
}
```

is there any more simple approach rather than using multiple dispatch call?